# When writing a tragic hero for a tragedy, do the readers have to sympathize with the characters?

Tags: creative-writing, characters, tragedies

I've been told that a tragic hero is a protagonist with a tragic flaw or a character defect that ultimately leads to their downfall and that the audience should sympathize with the character, even as they recognize their flaws.

I am wondering if it's ok if the audience doesn't sympathize with the character. I have a character who is extremely evil and unlikeable, an anti-hero type, so I am wondering if that's ok. I've seen a lot of people experimenting with genre and archetypes, and I was wondering if it's possible to write an effective tragedy with an unlikeable tragic hero who people can't sympathize with.

Comment: If we can't sympathise with them, why would we find their downfall tragic?

Comment: I thought so, but then I thought about Death Notes, but I am not sure if the main character of Death Notes is a tragic hero.

Comment: An antihero's downfall can be tragic. A villain protagonist's downfall can really only feel deserved. While it's implied that he was corrupted by power to an extent, and it does nothing to stop the audience from enjoying his exploits, Light falls squarely into the latter category.

Comment: In "Paradise Lost" we cannot allow ourselves to sympathize with Lucifer -- he's the ultimate bad guy -- but we do.

Comment: The Chronicles of Thomas Covenant kind of does this - quite possibly the most loathsome protagonist I've ever encountered.

Comment: @F1Krazy I don't sympathise with the government, and yet when the government do things that are stupid and predictable, I always find it tragic.

Comment: @Stef As do I, but that's because we sympathise with the people that their decisions affect. The tragedy lies with them, not with the government.

Comment: @SeanR I'm sure that I'm not the only one who found the series torture to get through, simply because of how little I liked Thomas Covenant (but my brother insisted it was good...).  I think that's the perfect example of why one shouldn't think the death of an unlikeable protagonist tragic - it might have made the series palatable to me if he had died at the end.

Comment: @UnrelatedString `A villain protagonist's downfall can really only feel deserved` true, but it's also true that a protagonist's path to villiany can indeed be tragic

Comment: @repomonster: *"When writing ..., do the readers... "* - actually, when writing, there are no readers. Because there is nothing to read in the first place. But I am no writer, what do I know. :)

Comment: They do not, and that's as much as anything due to with the wording of the Question.

Consider for instance, Beowulf, present as historical fact and re-written with the Grendel family as tragic heroes?

How would such a re-write change the story?

Unless the re-writer was extremely skilled, why the would readership switch allegiance to the Grendels, any more than they might to Dracula in similar circumstances… and please remember, several versions present Dracula as at worst, misguided.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I have a character who is extremely evil and unlikeable, ...

How did he get that way? I doubt that he was born evil and unlikable: the tragedy could be the way that someone who is initially OK gradually becomes warped. Macbeth is a brave, successful general, but, by the end of Act 1 he has been persuaded to murder his patron and frame two innocent servants. If Shakespeare had skipped the material from Act 1 we'd just have the evil and unlikable protagonist you describe. I suggest that you focus on how to warp his character.

Comment: Great example is Walter White. He is definitely not the "hero" of the story, but you see him go from Mr. Chips to Scarface in a logical progression of events, and though his arc ends with him still being bad, he does maybe one good thing. (Although even some have had said that was open to interpretation)

Comment: Here is another thought: have you read much of Borges? I suggest that you compare [Streetcorner Man](https://www.proquest.com/openview/7010fdbe66897416c787eb62c92fa28f/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=1820945) with the later [Rosendo's tale](https://apps.asdk12.org/staff/ruhlin_john/HOMEWORK/261141_RosendoJuarez.pdf). The same incident, and the same central character, but two totally different points of view: hero or cockroach?

Answer (score 9):

I really doubt that is possible.

Readers (because we are somewhat egotistical) tend to identify with the protagonist, or at least with one of the "main crew."

Even with a tragic flaw, I don't think we will identify with an evil character. Hero or not.

We can identify with a flawed hero, like a drug addict, or an autistic and emotionally distant hero (as in "The Accountant"), but in the end the autistic Accountant, despite working for mobsters and criminals, is still the Good bad guy, risking his life to save the innocent girl that he worked beside; with no romantic interest in her whatsoever.

We see the same thing in Léon: The Professional. The hero is a professional hit man, extremely good at his job; we see him working. But he chooses to protect a young innocent girl, saving her, with strictly a fatherly vibe, no sexual interest. (If you've heard there is, you've been lied to.)

You can have ruthless, violent, murderous heroes with flaws, but they have to be clearly doing something altruistically good as the plot of the story. Protecting somebody, setting something right, killing the corrupt, and taking risks they are not at all forced to take.

For me in writing, that is the definition of a hero: They are in the fight to do something altruistically good for others, or for everybody. And they could quit, when they get knocked down or beat up or set back or injured. They are given chances when it would be sensible to quit. But they don't. They get up and go on, despite their losses, even if they think they are likely to fail, because they'd rather **die** than fail.

Your hero must be doing something the audience can recognize as altruistically good.

Comment: The Professional is a nice example of a "good" bad guy because they show us 1) his code is "no women, no kids" and 2) in action he kills better armed evil bodyguards but spares the unarmed boss (of course The Professional isn't even close to a tragedy)

Comment: @OwenReynolds True, not a tragedy. I was using it as an example of a very bad, very flawed hero that is, nonetheless, doing something clearly altruistic by adopting and protecting this child, that is not his own, and that he hardly knows.

Comment: Counter-argument: look at how many people identify with and approve of characters like Walter White, or Tony Soprano, or to a lesser degree of awful Don Draper. There's tons of people who identify with immoral characters. Often with justifications for their actions, but sometimes without even that.

Comment: @JustinHilyard True, but Walter White at least **began** as a sympathetic character, a terminally ill man doing bad things to provide for his family. I know some people that stopped watching Breaking Bad when that motivation disappeared. Can't speak to Tony Soprano or Don Draper, I didn't bother watching them. But I'd wager there is some reason people watched them. Even Saul Goodman began as a sympathetic character, they made sure he got screwed, and was a Robin Hood cheating on behalf of people being wronged, at least in the early seasons.

Answer (score 8):

There is a difference between a hero and a protagonist. There is a difference between sympathy and empathy. There is a difference between relating to a character and connecting with them. From common thieves, mob bosses, assassins, serial killers and myriad monsters and demons, literature is rife with antiheroes and villainous main characters.

The reader need not approve of the character. The character need not have any redeemable qualities whatsoever. You will need to find other tactics to grab your reader's attention.

*Morbid curiosity/Macabre* - This is partly why the Sharon Tate murders are still talked about more than fifty years later.

*Psychological fascination* - Why Hannibal Lecter is so iconic. The character is thoroughly deplorable, and yet still the anchor of the series.

*Plot/Arc* - Though individual characters may have had *some* redeeming qualities, The Lannisters were deliciously despicable, as were the Corleones and Tattaglias. Fans loved watching the characters lie, swindle and kill each other.

*Negative Illustration* - You can make a statement about good (or broader social statement) through depicting evil, viz Alex DeLarge. (Admittedly, this narrative makes use of pretty much all the aforementioned devices, and is a master class of dystopian/antihero theme, but for sake of  just a character study is befitting.)

*Character Concept* - Here again, using any/all the above techniques, you devise a character with an interesting concept that titillates your readers, makes them want to explore what makes the character tick, or indulge in their darkness from the safety of the fourth wall,  and this list is nearly endless: Count Dracula, Travis Bickle, Char Aznable, Tyler Durden, ad nauseum (quite literally).

So no, the reader doesn't have to approve of the main character at all. There is a reason Jack the Ripper and Mike Meyers capture fans. There is a difference between an ethically good character and a conceptually good character.

And never underestimate the importance of just good writing.

Btw, the tragedy element is pretty basic IMO: it is what could-have-been. Flashes or hints of virtue appear from beneath the mire, never to be realized or allowed to shine. A character who *could* be likable, or lovable, or admirable, but through flaw (character-driven) or circumstance (plot-driven), never attains redemption, or love or what-have-you.

I would recommend reading up on some psychology; I personally don't believe in such a thing as pure evil or pure good; we are all faceted. So understanding  your character's thinking and *motivations* (not to mention the psychology/desires of your audience) may help you delve into the mind and nature of your character, and breathe a fuller life into your concept.

Then all you gotta do is write the devil out of it. 3:)

Comment: Jack the Ripper isn't a fictional character.  He's a serial killer who was never caught.  Most of the literature surrounding him has to do with the mystery of who he was and what his motives are.

Comment: Sharon Tate was not fictional either. Point remains; they are captivating.

Comment: Which is those real people are not invented characters and not relevant to a question about fictional characters.   Additional nitpick, but a lot of your references to fictional characters gloss over why those characters are compelling.   I'm not a fan of horror film and what little I do know of the recurring villains, Mike Meyers is the least interesting of the slasher sub-genre.

Comment: The Corleones were bad, but the hero was Michael, and when he began, he was clearly trying to distance himself from his criminal family. It is a tragic story because he felt forced into the life of crime by his criminal family circumstances, he could not walk away and abandon them in their time of need. He loved them despite their criminality. In a way, Michael was exacting Justice for the criminal actions taken against his family, and tragically ended up just like them.

Comment: Hannibal Lecter is not the hero in the movie, he is the villain. Jodie Foster's character Clarice Starling is the protagonist and hero of the story.

Comment: The question was: do readers need to sympathize with an extremely evil character? Short answer: of course not. Long answer: here's some examples and techniques.

Whether real-life events/people can be drawn as inspiration, and why A Clockwork Orange is a masterclass in narration/character is out of scope.

Comment: "When writing a tragic ***HERO*** for a category [...] I've been told that a tragic hero is a protagonist [...] and that the audience should sympathize with the ***character***, even as they recognize their flaws [...] I am wondering if it's ok if the audience doesn't sympathize with the character.." ---------- @kmunky Clearly the question refers to a tragic hero protagonist, and the "character" refers to **that hero.** You have misread "character" to mean "any character". Of course the audience doesn't have to sympathize with the bad guys, but they **do** have to sympathize with the **hero**.

Comment: @Amadeus Vito Corleone didn't start as a bad guy either: a Mafia boss had killed his father back in Sicily, so he moved to America to get away from that stuff. But he had a family to support and needed extra income...  IMHO the tragedy of the Godfather is a bit like one of the Greek tragedies, where The Agamemnon, and the [Libation Bearers](https://ir.canterbury.ac.nz/bitstream/handle/10092/10503/2%20-%20The%20Oresteia%20of%20Aeschylus%20-%20The%20Libation%20Bearers.pdf;sequence=2) are just 2 episodes in the way one family handles its curse. (A family that slays together stays together)

Comment: I wouldn't really classify *The Silence of the Lambs* as a tragedy specifically *because* the focus is not on empathizing with or seeing the inner conflict of the villains, but in the fascination of learning how these deeply disturbed people work. Obviously you *can* have such a character in your work but it's going to inevitably change how the audience responds, and it may not be appropriate to your genre.

Comment: @Amadeus My very first sentence: "There is a difference between a hero and a protagonist". Which is to say you need not relate to a character who is not a hero, and your MC need not be a hero. Cadence: I agree, in fact almost none of my examples are tragic, except maybe Char. Connecting with a consummately evil character seemed the crux of the issue imo, the tragedy aspect more elementary.

Comment: @kmunky Well, the OP specifically asked about "a tragic hero for a tragedy" so I'm guessing that aspect is important to them.

Comment: The question is "if it's possible to write an effective tragedy with an unlikeable tragic hero who people can't sympathize with" Do you find the downfall of the people/characters you used as examples to be _tragic_? Do you feel sorry for them at the end? "A character who could be likable, or lovable, or admirable, but through flaw (character-driven) or circumstance (plot-driven), never attains redemption, or love or what-have-you." sounds to me like a character that you can feel sympathy for even if you don't like them.

Answer (score 7):

Sure, I can think of several examples --*Lolita,* *The Talented Mr Ripley,* and *Match Point* for tragedies, *Young Adult* or *Youth in Revolt* for a more comic take, *A Clockwork Orange* or *Fight Club* for less easily categorized examples.

The audience doesn't always need to sympathize with the main character, but they do expect to learn something from the person's journey, which means they need to empathize to at least a limited extent. There's often a moral lesson to be discerned, even if the main character never learns it. In *Ripley* and *Match Point,* for example, the MC destroys their own chance at love and happiness. We learn from them that even an unpunished sociopathic life is its own hell. Similarly, the villain/protagonist of *Lolita* self-destructs, even though he initially seems to have gotten away with his crimes scot-free. Both he, and the narcissistic hero of *Young Adult* experience a brief moment of moral self-awareness late in the narrative. In all of these cases we can view it, and think to ourselves "If that were me, I would have made better choices."

In both *Orange* and *Fight Club* there's something magnetic about the sociopathic central characters. Audiences may neither sympathize nor empathize with them, yet still find something to admire in their struggle to wrest the most out of life, and their opposition to being crushed by the steamroller of the status quo.

Comment: And Goodfellas.  We don't sympathize with Henry Hill, but we're interested in watching his easy corruption and long downfall.

Answer (score 6):

In the official tragedy, Shakespeare's "Titus Andronicus", the hero isn't exactly likable, but we can respect him. His good points are: being a hero general just back from saving Rome (several times), lost several of his sons in those wars and took it in stride, and he turned down being the emperor. That's pretty much the back-story for every cheesy action hero today -- a modest hero who's made great sacrifices for the nation. We'd like to see the guy live on his farm in peace, even if we wouldn't visit him much.

Then he human sacrifices an enemy in retaliation. That was legal and his right and you can see why he did it, but still ... . He's also such a rigid military man that he won't stand up to the new emperor for his remaining family. And he expects his kids to follow his orders, like modern day military movie dads, and is furious when they won't. He also tricks someone into eating a pie made from their own children, but by that time he's clearly gone mad.

So all-in-all his flaws are pretty bad, but they're still flaws -- he's not Evil. But his enemies are Evil -- four of them who are monsters in different ways. And what happens to him and his family is so much worse than he deserved.

Answer (score 5):

The main protagonist in the short story [The Spider’s Thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spider%27s_Thread) is a genuinely unlikable character, a murderer and thief, throughout the story. And yet, the reader is subconsciously rooting for him all the time.

How is that achieved? The problem in the question seems to be a semantic one for me. A hero is *by definition* the character in the story the reader is most interested and invested in. This requires a certain level of sympathy, where sympathy is quite literally the “feeling his feelings” part that keeps the fictional story interesting for the reader.

Akutagawa uses a two-fold trick to make the character approachable. One is a single good deed that he did in the past. This serves then as hook for off-loading the work of feeling sympathy with this character to a god-like Buddha, who appears in the frame story. The reader is then in the position to be invested in the character’s fate without having to know motivations and reasons for the character’s bad acts.

Comment: Thanks for drawing my attention to Akutagawa. I hadn't heard of him, but Wikipedia tells me that he inspired Rashomon.

Comment: Great example. Also referred to as [Pet The Dog/Save The Cat trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PetTheDog).

Answer (score 1):

In real life, as well as in *Schindler's List* and *Shindler's Ark*: Oskar Schindler.

He was a deeply flawed man. A drunkard, a womanizer, a man willing to become rich out of property stolen from others and forced labour. In most circumstances he would have been fairly detestable.

And yet, there was a moral line he would not cross, which far too many others did. They simply pretended that they didn't know what the Nazis were doing, or "simply followed orders". He put his life on the line to save as many as he could.

Why is the antonym of bad, good, and the antonym of evil, good? And yet bad and evil seem to be two utterly different concepts, and that difference is brought into focus by this man.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to understand about a tragic flaw in classic tragedy is that the flaw is often one of the very traits that makes the hero successful and heroic. To be a real tragedy, the hero (this can apply to a villian) must rise above others, the higher the better, and subsequently fall, the lower the better, because of the same qualities. I do agree that it is challenging to make the fall of a villain feel like a bad thing. Are you sure you're really meaning to write a tragedy?